# How to change the port of Tomcat 7 from 8080 to 80 and Secure Port to 443 on RHEL 7.4

Tags: tomcat7, redhat, rhel, rhel7

How to change the port of Tomcat 7 from 8080 to 80 and Secure Port to 443 on RHEL 7.4.

I have done the change in Server.xml file but no use, it is not redirecting, If use some other ports the site is working perfectly fine.

Help

Comment: my current configuration (server.xml).

Comment: <Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />

Comment: <Connector port="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
                keyAlias="*.mydomain.com"
                keystoreFile="/var/lib/tomcat/ssl.jks"
                keystorePass="xxxxxxx" />

Comment: It's hard to read configuration files in comments.  Can you please edit your question and put the contents of the file in the question with four spaces at the beginning of each line?

Comment: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/managing_confined_services/sect-managing_confined_services-configuration_examples-changing_port_numbers